# How would I make a text box only become visible when another text box contains text in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am creating an asp.net form in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. I have a text box for Street1 and only want one for Street2 to appear if the user enters something into Street1. How would I accomplish this in Javascript? Or if there is a better way to accomplish in C#, how would I do it that way?

Here is my HTML code:

```
        <div class="col">
            <asp:TextBox ID="Street1" class="form-control" placeholder="Street1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <asp:TextBox ID="Street2" class="form-control" placeholder="Street2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script>
    var Street1 = document.getElementById('<%= Street1.ClientID %>');
    var Street2 = document.getElementById('<%= Street2.ClientID %>');

    Street1.Value.addEventListener('input', function () {
        var Street1 = document.getElementById('<%= Street1.ClientID %>');
        var Street2 = document.getElementById('<%= Street2.ClientID %>');
        if (Street1.Value != "") {
            Street2.style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            Street2.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Though the Street1 Text box is empty, Street2 is still visible with my code.

Comment: Why would you want to accomplish this with C#? C# runs on the server, not the client side. Keep in mind how the web works - the server generates the HTML/CSS/JS which is sent to the client. At that point, the server is no longer in the picture unless you initiate a new request.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there... I've not changed much in your code, just a couple of points.  Use javascript `element.value` rather than the ASP.NET `object.Value` (note lowercase v for javascript).

The reason it's still showing is that there is no css applied when the page loads.  Add simple css to hide `Street2` textbox initially on page load: `#Street2 { display: none; }`.

The snippet below shows it's possible with minor changes.

```js
var Street1 = document.getElementById('Street1');
var Street2 = document.getElementById('Street2');

Street1.addEventListener('input', function () {
  // already have a reference to Street1 and Street2 from above, no need to declare again
  
  // use javascript value not asp.net Value (lowercase 'v')
  if (Street1.value) {
    Street2.style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    Street2.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#Street2 { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <input type="text" ID="Street1" class="form-control" placeholder="Street1" runat="server"/>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <input type="text" ID="Street2" class="form-control" placeholder="Street2" runat="server"/>
</div>
```